# how to calulated length with respect to two column entries

Tags: sql, ms-access

can the below mentioned code be made more compact, I am trying to calulate length of cable for same rack to same rack insatallation where the length is fixed to 6mts and then from one rack to the other rack each incremented by .5mtrs and the remaining are some random length
The Database r having the following columns

```
ID        RACK_A           RACK_B          LENGTH
1          RK 1             RK 1
2          RK 2             RK 1
3          RK 1             RK 2
4          MCR DESK         PCR
5          CAR              INGEST
6          PCR              CAR
```

AND so on about 2000 entries

```
UPDATE MASTER_SCHEDULE
SET CABLE_LENTH = 
    switch(
          RACK_A='RK 1' AND RACK_B='RK 1', 6
        , RACK_A='RK 2' AND RACK_B='RK 2', 6
        , RACK_A='RK 3' AND RACK_B='RK 3', 6
        , RACK_A='RK 4' AND RACK_B='RK 4', 6
        , RACK_A='RK 5' AND RACK_B='RK 5', 6
        , RACK_A='RK 6' AND RACK_B='RK 6', 6
        , RACK_A='RK 7' AND RACK_B='RK 7', 6
and so on say more 20 statements all with LENGTH = 6

        , RACK_A='RK 1' AND RACK_B='RK 2' OR RACK_A = 'RK 2' AND RACK_B = 'RK 1',6.5
        , RACK_A='RK 1' AND RACK_B='RK 3' OR RACK_A = 'RK 3' AND RACK_B = 'RK 1',7
        , RACK_A='RK 1' AND RACK_B='RK 4' OR RACK_A = 'RK 4' AND RACK_B = 'RK 1',7.5
        , RACK_A='RK 1' AND RACK_B='RK 5' OR RACK_A = 'RK 5' AND RACK_B = 'RK 1',8
        , RACK_A='RK 1' AND RACK_B='RK 6' OR RACK_A = 'RK 6' AND RACK_B = 'RK 1',8.5
        , RACK_A='RK 1' AND RACK_B='RK 7' OR RACK_A = 'RK 7' AND RACK_B = 'RK 1',9
and so on each LENGTH incremented by +.5

      ,  RACK_A= 'MCR DESK' AND RACK_B='PCR=' OR RACK_A= 'PCR' AND RACK_B='MCR_DESK',54
      ,  RACK_A= 'CAR' AND RACK_B='INGEST' OR RACK_A= 'INGEST' AND RACK_B='CAR',47 
  and so on each length is random figure ,        
        , true, 0)
WHERE ID>=1 AND ID<= 2000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From sample data given here, I assumed that all data in column RACK_A and RACK_B has format "RK {Room Number}". Then you can try this query :

```
UPDATE MASTER_SCHEDULE
SET CABLE_LENTH = 
    ABS((RIGHT(RACK_A, LEN(RACK_A)-3) - RIGHT(RACK_B, LEN(RACK_B)-3)))
        *
    0.5
        +
    6
WHERE ID>=1 AND ID<= 2000
```

For reference : [MS Access: Functions](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/index.php)

Comment: it give me Data type mismatch in criteria expression CODE 3030 SQLSTATE 22005

Comment: make sure my assumption is correct : "*all data in column RACK_A and RACK_B has format "RK {Room Number}"*". Otherwise, the query won't work, and we need to find another way to get room number from RACK_A and RACK_B.

Comment: what is data type for `CABLE_LENTH` column?

Comment: The datatype of length field was SHORTTEXT, I tryed changing to NUMBER  but same error it giving

Comment: not sure, I tested that with column of type Number and it worked. If field type is SHORTEXT try to wrap expression after `=` with Cstr like `SET CABLE_LENTH = Cstr(ABS..... * 0.5 + 6)`. Don't have MS Access to test right now.

Comment: no idea. It does work here (ms access 2013), even if I change CABLE_LENTH field to type SHORTTEXT (and even without Cstr function).

Comment: Yes it works with ms access 2013 but i am trying to access these database from autocad using ODBC and SQL QUERY for which i am getting that error

Comment: I have changed ABS((MID(RACK,3)-MID(RACK_B,3))) & it working with my application. Will it do the same job as the above query

Comment: I think yes, `MID()` as in your comment above will do the same job as `RIGHT()` in this answer

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for SQL Server, I will provide you the code for MS ACCESS too in few moments. But in case you know the analogous functions of MS-ACCESS I used in the query, then you can try the conversion yourself

```
UPDATE MASTER_SCHEDULE
SET LENGTH = ABS( CAST(SUBSTRING(RACK_A, CHARINDEX(' ',RACK_A)+1, LEN(RACK_A) - CHARINDEX   (' ',RACK_A)) AS INT)
-  CAST(SUBSTRING(RACK_B, CHARINDEX(' ',RACK_B)+1, LEN(RACK_B) - CHARINDEX(' ',RACK_B)) AS INT))  * 0.5 + 6
```

What I am doing in the query to extract integer portion of columns `RACK_A` and `RACK_B`, subtract the values, take absolute of the result (required if the subtraction results in a negative value), multiply by 0.5 and lastly add 6 to it.

see it working at SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0abad/1

Here is corresponding code for MS-ACCESS:

```
UPDATE MASTER_SCHEDULE SET MASTER_SCHEDULE.LENGTH = Abs(CInt(Mid(RACK_A,InStr(1,RACK_A,' ')+1,Len(RACK_A)-InStr(1,RACK_A,' ')))-CInt(Mid(RACK_B,InStr(1,RACK_B,' ')+1,Len(RACK_B)-InStr(1,RACK_B,' '))))*0.5+6;
```

Let me know if it worked as expected.

Comment: it give me Data type mismatch in criteria expression CODE 3030 SQLSTATE 22005

Comment: what is the datatype of length field?

Comment: The datatype of length field was SHORTTEXT, I tryed changing to NUMBER  but same error it giving

Comment: try enclosing the expression within CSTR before assigning it to MASTER_SCHEDULE.LENGTH